# how to use active class in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to change the text color when a component is active.

**Here's my template-**

```
<div
  v-if="enabled2FAs.includes('phoneOtp')"
  @click="otpType = 'phoneOtp'"
  >
  <div
    :class="[isActive ? activeClass: 'red',]">
    Phone OTP
  </div>
</div>
<div
  v-if="enabled2FAs.includes('authenticatorApp')"
  @click="otpType = 'authenticatorApp'"
  >
  <div
    :class="[isActive ? activeClass: 'red',]">
    Phone OTP
  </div>
</div>
```

**my script tag-**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: true,
    };
  },
 
};
</script>
```

pleaase how can i go about this

Comment: `activeClass` is a string or a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using string interpolation;

```html
<div :class="`${isActive ? activeClass : 'red'}`">
    Phone OTP
</div>
```

This allows you to add non-dynamic classes in the future

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple workarounds to achieve this as per the [`documentation`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes), One of them is binding to an object.

```
<div :class="classObject"></div>
```

And as per the logic, You can dynamically update it with the help of computed property.

```
data() {
  return {
    isActive: true
  }
},
computed: {
  classObject() {
    return {
      'activeClass': this.isActive,
      'red': !this.isActive
    }
  }
}
```